# QGIS crashes frequently since upgrading to 2.18.2 on Mac

Tags: qgis, mac

I upgraded QGIS to 2.18.2 from here http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis.

I did note this warning there:

`WARNING: QGIS will crash if Qt4 developer components are installed in the standard /Developer location. Either rename /Developer/Applications/Qt/Plugins or uninstall Qt before running QGIS.`

But I don't see Qt4 installed there.  Maybe I'm not searching correctly, as I'm still somewhat new to the Mac paradigm and finding the install locations of software.

The crashes happen most often when I'm dragging or zooming a map, and I get a Mac problem report that includes this information (I'm not pasting the entire report because it is pretty long):

I'm curious if others have encountered this and how you resolved it?

```
Process:               QGIS [44719]
Path:                  /Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/QGIS
Identifier:            org.qgis.qgis2
Version:               2.18.2 (2.18.2 [exported])
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           QGIS [44719]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2017-03-02 09:16:43.972 -0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F27)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        4C33FF15-D5BB-A25F-93B6-A78DE682F1A7

Sleep/Wake UUID:       6F832B34-2C1A-48B1-88B5-58CC530EFAE8

Time Awake Since Boot: 1700000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       6500 seconds

Crashed Thread:        18  Thread (pooled)

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       EXC_I386_GPFLT

Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   QtGui                           0x000000010fc0eb58 QIcon::~QIcon() + 24
1   QtGui                           0x000000010ff669fe QDockWidgetTitleButton::sizeHint() const + 238
2   QtGui                           0x000000010ff66c12 QDockWidgetLayout::titleHeight() const + 194
3   QtGui                           0x000000010ff67678 QDockWidgetLayout::sizeFromContent(QSize const&, bool) const + 856
4   QtGui                           0x000000010ff6aa82 QDockWidgetItem::minimumSize() const + 146
5   QtGui                           0x000000010ff6e9b1 QDockAreaLayoutItem::minimumSize() const + 97
6   QtGui                           0x000000010ff6e506 QDockAreaLayoutInfo::minimumSize() const + 166
7   QtGui                           0x000000010ff6ea12 QDockAreaLayoutItem::minimumSize() const + 194
8   QtGui                           0x000000010ff6e506 QDockAreaLayoutInfo::minimumSize() const + 166
9   QtGui                           0x000000010ff6e738 QDockAreaLayout::minimumSize() const + 200
10  QtGui                           0x000000010ff9b6e6 QMainWindowLayoutState::minimumSize() const + 38
```

Comment: Someone else recently posted a similar issue http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/234853/qgis-quit-unexpectedly-at-startup-on-mac Not that it has answer yet, but just so that you are aware that you are not alone

Comment: I have found the kyngchaos version of 2.18 to be very unstable, frequently crashing and reporting mac errors, and then reporting a slew of plugin (usually processing) errors when I reopened.  I kept having to uninstall and delete all of my user folders.

I've found the installation from homebrew to be much more stable.  There is a walkthrough here: http://usabilityetc.com/2016/06/how-to-install-qgis-with-homebrew/ and although it's slightly out of date it works.

Comment: I have also had the same issues since upgrading. However, mine are related to the system crashing when trying to add vector delimited layers... It is unfortunate but I have lost 2 hours trying to conduct work arounds and reinstalls. However, with that being said it *is* stated in the downloads there maybe some stability issues from QGIS 2.18.9 to Mac. Was previously on 2.18.2 (I think)

Answer (score 2):

Confirm that you have uninstalled and reinstalled all of the elements in kyngchaos' `.dmg` file.

I was having the same problem of persistent crashing with QGIS 2.18.2, until this afternoon.

My crash reports were mostly the same as those you pasted in, except that my Mac OS version is 10.12.3, and the following details:

> Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
>   Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000500000009
>   Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>
> Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
>   Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
>   Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

I uninstalled and then reinstalled all 4 components in kyngchaos's .dmg file, in the order they are numbered.

In the previous installation, as silly as it seems in hindsight, I did not install the python and matplot elements, presuming that only GDAL was obligatory. There are two readme files in the expanded installation package, however, and the second highlights the importance of installing all four elements.

Since re-installing I have been able to zoom all over the place and go back and forth between maps and composer elements without crashing, whereas it had been impossible to work previously.

UPDATE: crashing still occurs if I switch out to other programs, in full screen mode at least.