# "QGIS quit unexpectedly" at startup on Mac

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am having for a few months an issue with QGIS on my mac. Every time I start the program, QGIS crash with “QGIS quit unexpectedly”. The program starts only once I select “Reopen” in the message box. This is not dramatic but a bit annoying…

I have been using QGIS for a while on this laptop, and I suspect that the problem comes from the fact that I still have some traces of previous versions that are conflicting.

I already tried several things:

- Reinstall QGIS
- Remove all the plugins
- Remove the content of .qgis folder

These steps did not solve the problem and I am now out of ideas.

My config: MAC OS 10.11.5 QGIS 2.18

Comment: Have you tried the LTR (Long term release / Long term support version) 2.14 ? This is the version that is considered to be stable.

Comment: The crash is not specific to QGIS 2.18. I had this issue for some time and if I remember well it actually started when I upgraded to 2.14. It looks more like a plugin issue or a conflict with old install files than a QGIS bug to me..

Answer (score 1):

"WARNING: QGIS will crash if Qt4 developer components are installed in the standard /Developer location. Either rename /Developer/Applications/Qt/Plugins or uninstall Qt before running QGIS."

This was the reason why QGIS was crashing, now it works normally.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Are there old maps on your 2.18 version that you created with the previous version?

If so, have you tried opening those old maps and checking to see if some of the layers have to be redirected to back to the source of the file. Some of your old maps might have layers that need to be redirected, and maybe that is what is making your QGIS crash.

Comment: Do you mean the files in my recent projects?QGIS crashes even when I run the application without opening a file (before displaying the loading splash screen).

Comment: Yes, any of your previous maps. If it is occuring during the splash screen then I would assume that is an error on the install. 

In the IT department where I work a similar situation happened to me with my Arc programs. I would try and open the program, a splash screen would come up like it is loading, but after a minute or two it just disappeared. That was an install problem, but yours works after you click "Reopen" which is odd.

Comment: One thing we had to do to fix the issue was create a new user account. Maybe if you create a new user through System Preferences->Users & Groups->Add a User Account. That might fix the bug, but then you would most likely have to transfer your files over to the new user account.

Comment: I just tried to create a new user on my Mac, but I still have the same problem..

Comment: Are you positive it's not an installation problem? I know it that it can be a pain downloading on Mac compared to Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me on two different computers after the latest MacOS update.

Try these steps in the link below for a clean install.
http://www.underdiverwaterman.com/clean-install-of-qgis-in-osx/

And then simply install it again. Worked for me.

Good luck.

Comment: I reinstalled QGIS following the procedure that you mentioned but this didn't solve the problem. However, while downloading QGIS again, I saw a warning on kyngchaos website: 

"WARNING: QGIS will crash if Qt4 developer components are installed in the standard /Developer location. Either rename /Developer/Applications/Qt/Plugins or uninstall Qt before running QGIS."

This was the reason why QGIS was crashing, now it works normally. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this [build of QGIS](http://nextgis.com/nextgis-qgis/) - it based on QGIS 2.14.15 LTR but does not depends on system libraries and qt creator.

Nice update system included - no need to install/reinstall.